# data.table: “group counter” for a specific combination of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to add a counter column in a data frame based on a set of identical rows. To do this, I used the package `data.table`. In my case, the comparison between rows need doing from the combination of columns "z" AND ("x" OR "y").

I tested:

```
DF[ , Index := .GRP, by = c("x","y","z") ]
```

but the result is the combination of "z" AND "x" AND "y".

How can I have the combination of "z" AND ("x" OR "y") ?

Here is a data example:

```
DF = data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","b","c","d","e","f","f"), y=c(1,3,2,8,8,4,4,6,0), z=c("M","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","F"))
DF <- data.table(DF)
```

I would like to have this output:

```
> DF
   x y z Index
1: a 1 M   1
2: a 3 M   1
3: a 2 M   1
4: b 8 F   2
5: c 8 F   2
6: d 4 M   3
7: e 4 M   3
8: f 6 F   4
9: f 0 F   4
```

Comment: FYI, you can create your data set using `data.table` without using `data.frame`. Or alternatively convert your `data.frame` to a `data.table` without copies using `setDT`. Also, what should be the desired output for cases such as `data.table(x = c("a", "a", "a"), y = c(1, 1, 2), z = c("M", "F", "F"))`?

Comment: For your example, `DF[, Index:=rleid(z)]` will work, but it is only considering "Z" and not ("x" OR "y").

Comment: Ok, and the output for `data.table(x = c("b", "a", "a"), y = c(1, 1, 2), z = c("F", "F", "F"))`?

Comment: Thank you very much David for your advice. The output will be: data.table(x = c("a", "a", "a"), y = c(1, 1, 2), z = c("M", "F", "F"), Index = c(1,2,2))

Comment: I've updated the comment, see above

Comment: @David: Very good example. The output will be: `data.table(x = c("b", "a", "a"), y = c(1, 1, 2), z = c("F", "F", "F"), Index = c(1,1,1))`

Answer (score 6):

The new group starts if the value for `z` is changing **or** the values both for `x` **and** `y` are changing.

Try this example.

```
require(data.table)

DF <- data.table(x = c("a","a","a","b","c","d","e","f","f"),
                 y = c(1,3,2,8,8,4,4,6,0),
                 z=c("M","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","F"))

# The functions to compare if value is not equal with the previous value
is.not.eq.with.lag <- function(x) c(T, tail(x, -1) != head(x, -1))

DF[, x1 := is.not.eq.with.lag(x)]
DF[, y1 := is.not.eq.with.lag(y)]
DF[, z1 := is.not.eq.with.lag(z)]
DF

DF[, Index := cumsum(z1 | (x1 & y1))]
DF
```

Comment: IIUC, will this work: `pmin(rleid(dt$x, dt$y), rleid(dt$z))`?

Comment: @Arun I think this won't work for times when there is only a pattern in `z` but no patterns in neither `x` or `y`, such as `DF <- data.table(x = c("f", "r"), y = c(6, 0), z = c("F", "F"))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it'd return all 1s. Isn't it what should be the result? djhurio, thanks! Your first line explains it clearly...

Comment: @Arun, I think it should return two separate groups, as djhurios solution would.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think I get it now.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of people warn against a `for` loop in R, but in this instance I think it is a very direct way of approaching the problem. Plus, the result isn't growing in size so performance issues aren't a large issue. The `for` loop approach would be:

```
    dt$grp <- rep(NA,nrow(dt))
    for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
        if (i == 1){
          dt$grp[i] = 1
        }
        else {
          if(dt$z[i-1] == dt$z[i] & (dt$x[i-1] == dt$x[i] | dt$y[i-1] == dt$y[i])){
            dt$grp[i] = dt$grp[i-1]
          }else{
            dt$grp[i] = dt$grp[i-1] + 1
          }
        }
    }
```

Trying this on OPs original problem, the result is:

```
DF = data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","b","c","d","e","f","f"), y=c(1,3,2,8,8,4,4,6,0), z=c("M","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","F"))
dt <- data.table(DF)
dt$grp <- rep(NA,nrow(dt))
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
    if (i == 1){
      dt$grp[i] = 1
    }
    else {
      if(dt$z[i-1] == dt$z[i] & (dt$x[i-1] == dt$x[i] | dt$y[i-1] == dt$y[i])){
        dt$grp[i] = dt$grp[i-1]
      }else{
        dt$grp[i] = dt$grp[i-1] + 1
      }
    }
}
dt

   x y z grp
1: a 1 M   1
2: a 3 M   1
3: a 2 M   1
4: b 8 F   2
5: c 8 F   2
6: d 4 M   3
7: e 4 M   3
8: f 6 F   4
9: f 0 F   4
```

Trying this on the `data.table` in @Frank's comment, gives the expected result as well:

```
dt<-data.table(x = c("b", "a", "a"), y = c(1, 1, 2), z = c("F", "F", "F"))
dt$grp <- rep(NA,nrow(dt))
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
    if (i == 1){
      dt$grp[i] = 1
    }
    else {
      if(dt$z[i-1] == dt$z[i] & (dt$x[i-1] == dt$x[i] | dt$y[i-1] == dt$y[i])){
        dt$grp[i] = dt$grp[i-1]
      }else{
        dt$grp[i] = dt$grp[i-1] + 1
      }
    }
}
dt

   x y z grp
1: b 1 F   1
2: a 1 F   1
3: a 2 F   1
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED TO ADD: This solution is in some ways a more verbose version of the one advocated by [djhurio above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37865648/1332389). I think it shows what is happening a bit more so I'll leave it.

I think this is a task easier to do if it is broken down a little bit. The below code creates TWO indices at first, one for changes in `x` (nested in `z`) and one for changes in `y` (nested in `z`). We then find the first row from each of these indices. Taking the cumulative sum of the case where both FIRST.x and FIRST.y is true should give your desired index.

```
library(data.table)

dt_example <- data.table(x = c("a","a","a","b","c","d","e","f","f"),
                         y = c(1,3,2,8,8,4,4,6,0),
                         z = c("M","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","F"))

dt_example[,Index_x := .GRP,by = c("z","x")]
dt_example[,Index_y := .GRP,by = c("z","y")]

dt_example[,FIRST.x := !duplicated(Index_x)]
dt_example[,FIRST.y := !duplicated(Index_y)]

dt_example[,Index := cumsum(FIRST.x & FIRST.y)]
dt_example

   x y z Index_x Index_y FIRST.x FIRST.y Index
1: a 1 M       1       1    TRUE    TRUE     1
2: a 3 M       1       2   FALSE    TRUE     1
3: a 2 M       1       3   FALSE    TRUE     1
4: b 8 F       2       4    TRUE    TRUE     2
5: c 8 F       3       4    TRUE   FALSE     2
6: d 4 M       4       5    TRUE    TRUE     3
7: e 4 M       5       5    TRUE   FALSE     3
8: f 6 F       6       6    TRUE    TRUE     4
9: f 0 F       6       7   FALSE    TRUE     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach looks for changes in `x & z | y & z`. The extra columns are left in the data.table to show the calculations.

```
DF[, c("Ix", "Iy", "Iz", "dx", "dy", "min.change", "Index") := 
     #Create index of values based on consecutive order
     list(ix <- rleid(x), iy <- rleid(y), iz <- rleid(z),
          #Determine if combinations of x+z OR y+z change
          ix1 <- c(0, diff(rleid(ix+iz))), 
          iy1 <- c(0, diff(rleid(iy+iz))),
          #Either combination is constant (no change)?
          change <- pmin(ix1, iy1),
          #New index based on change
          cumsum(change) + 1
          )]

   x y z Ix Iy Iz dx dy min.change Index
1: a 1 M  1  1  1  0  0          0     1
2: a 3 M  1  2  1  0  1          0     1
3: a 2 M  1  3  1  0  1          0     1
4: b 8 F  2  4  2  1  1          1     2
5: c 8 F  3  4  2  1  0          0     2
6: d 4 M  4  5  3  1  1          1     3
7: e 4 M  5  5  3  1  0          0     3
8: f 6 F  6  6  4  1  1          1     4
9: f 0 F  6  7  4  0  1          0     4
```